# Why is adding an SSLContext or SslFilter to my Apache Mina service stopping all messages?

Tags: java, ssl, apache-mina

So I have an Apache Mina service where I am sending messages between two clients. I decided to add SSL doing the following:

```
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sslContext.init(null, null, null);
        SslFilter sslFilter = new SslFilter(sslContext);
        getService().getFilterChain().addFirst("sslFilter", sslFilter);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        log.warn("Failed to establish SSLFitler");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

So after adding this piece of code it appears that the clients still do connect, however none of my messages seem to be sending between the two (they were before adding this). Any idea what I may be missing?